# Copy large object field into remote PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-fdw

We have configured `postgres_fdw` to move data from a DB to remote DB. It works fine but the large object field's data in source db not getting copied to remote DB.

This is the statement used to copy:

```
INSERT INTO archive_remote.target_db(id, oid_field)
SELECT a.id, a.oid_field
FROM appl.source_db a
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Both databases are Postgres 9.6.

What is the right way to fix this?

Comment: What DB type is the remote DB, if it's not Postgres? What data type is the `oid_field` column on the foreign DB?  Is it an actual OID (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datatype-oid.html ) in the source table? Need more information

Comment: added details in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the `oid` in question is the Oid of a [large object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html), and you are wondering why the large object isn't copied when the `oid` field is copied.

Large objects cannot be copied via postgres_fdw. You'd have to use the large object API (or `pg_dump`) to move them from one database to the other. If the Oids are already taken on the second database, you'll have to use different ones and update the table accordingly.

Large objects are cumbersome to handle.

Comment: If used lo_get as shown below? INSERT INTO archive_remote.target_db(id, oid_field)
SELECT a.id, lo_get(a.oid_field)
FROM appl.source_db a
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

Comment: Actually as per the query I am executing above query from local which reads lo value in local and inserts into similar table on the remote DB. Without lo_get, only the large object id is saved. But now we are using lo_get() which will persist the actual large object value, right?

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion. Yes, that will work, as long as `oid_field` on the remote database is of type `bytea`.

Comment: In our case, the oid_field on the remote database is of type oid.

Comment: Then it won't work, because you cannot insert a `bytea` into an `oid`. The large object API is not accessible via foreign data wrapper. You'll have to think of a different way of transferring your large objects, e.g. using client code.

Comment: We have converted them to bytea and then copied using query INSERT INTO archive_remote.target_db(id, bytea_field)
SELECT a.id, a.bytea_field
FROM appl.source_db a
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;